# Cannot edit registry via BAT file but command-line works fine

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry, command-prompt

So 
Strange thing happend today. I was writing some *.bat which edits some registry values. 
Just for example, let's say that the command is this:

```
@ECHO ON 
REG add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v "NoPreviewPane" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f 
PAUSE
```

If I type (paste) this to elevated CMD, it works as it should. 
But if I create a *.bat file with that command and run it: 
 - run as administrator: cmd opens and closes, and nothing happens 
 - run normally: "access denied" - which is ok, because editing from cmd requires admin rights, afaik.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I have a pause after the command, that's not the issue. 
Which path - the HKEY.... path? Yes, it is correct. I said that this same command works when I paste it in CMD, but doesn't run from BAT file... nor does any other REG-related command.

Comment: The path command. If you have pause then why didn't you post the output.

Comment: The question title gives the wrong idea that a file with .BAT extension don't works, but a file with .CMD extension works fine. This is confusing. I suggest you to change "but CMD works fine" by "but command-line works fine".

Comment: Is this ALL that is in your bat file? The reason I ask is that  the current directory is changed when you run as admin. See for yourself by adding this line to very beginning of bat file. echo(%cd% & pause. If you are referencing relative files you won't find them. Add this line to beginning of bat file if that is the case: pushd %~dp0

Comment: @Aacini - thanks for title suggestion, You're right about that :)

Comment: @RGuggisberg - You got me wrong - it not about paths at all... it's just the fact that when I try to add a reg value via command-line it works, and when I weite that same command in bat file and run it - it doesn't work :/

Comment: It is about paths. POST THE SCREEN OUTPUT

Comment: @RGuggisberg There is no (file) path involved here, this script just uses `REG` to add a key to the registry.  This can be done from ANY folder

Comment: Not if your path is incorrect. That's why we keep saying post the output. This is a superuser question as it's about a misconfigured computer.

Comment: @bgalea There is no output > check the code once more (edited). As Tersosauros said, it's just a plain simple REG ADD command.

Comment: Also, as I stated in the  OP, when I run the bat file as admin: it opens and closes instantly - my best guess is that some strange things happens in the background maybe. Because, normally, because of the PAUSE at the end of the bat file, CMD should stay opened.

Comment: Just type path and post the output.

Comment: And Running as admin if you are an admin does not change the user. If you aren't admin you have to enter a username/password.

Answer (score 2):

So, after a night of research, I came accross [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/09/04/739820.aspx) solution. I reset the registry permissions as shown in the link. After that, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` *changes* when the *current user* changes (*i.e.* to Administrator).

You will need to make your script write to the relevant sub-key of `HKEY_CURRENT_USERS` instead - note the **S** at the end.
(See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6536e34-efee-4b43-b189-8f2e41151d75/uac-elevation-and-writing-to-hkeycurrentuser?forum=windowscompatibility) for a bit more on this.)

Comment: There is only one user on my machine - me (admin). So there is no chance that some kind of user changing happens.

Answer (score 0):

64 bit OS? Which CMD.exe are you using? YES... there is a 32 bit one and a 64 bit one! You are probably writing to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software... in one case and to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node in the other case. Do REG ADD /? if on a 64 bit OS and you will see the parameter to specify 32/64 bit area of registry.

Otherwise add the line @ECHO ON on the line before your REG ADD and PAUSE on the line after and see if there is an error message.

Comment: I edited the code in the OP. In the bat itself there ARE "@echo on" and "pause" commands. And as I stated before: when I run it as admin, the cmd just opens and instantly closes.